# UIButton does not remember its state in the tableView when using UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, parse-platform

I'm having problems with the reuse of custom cell in my tableview.

My tableView as I said has a custom cell where inside there is a button that sends or cancels a friend request to the user of that particular cell ...

in this TableView I also have a UISearchBar to filter the user of the app ..

The reuse of cells in normal mode works fine, but when I go to filter the user can not maintain the state of the button as in normal mode ...

Example ..

TableView I search mode:

If the user sends a request to Richard Marx button turns orange flowing properly, and even if the tableview nothing happens so far so good ... but if you use the UISearchBar does not match the orange button more than 'the cell containing Mr. Richard Marx but to Mr. Abram Van Helsing which happens to be the first in the list in search mode.

I've created an array that fits the users clicked but only seems to work if you are not using the UISearchBar 
Can you help me in any way?

**This is the realization of the Array used to filter the status of the button in the cell**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int i = NO;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {

            [self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NO]];

    }

}
```

**This method is inserted in cellForRowAtIndexPath I turn on or off button**

```
 UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cell.myContentView viewWithTag:100];
    UIImage *imageFriendAdd = [UIImage imageNamed:@"On_userAddFriend@2x"];

    if (myButton == nil) {
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(264.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        [myButton setBackgroundImage:imageFriendAdd forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.tag = 100;
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:andEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.myContentView addSubview:myButton];


        NSLog(@" BUTTON CREATED !!!");

    }  else {

    }




    if ([self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray [indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
        UIImage *imageFriendAddOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"On_userAddFriend@2x"];
        [myButton setBackgroundImage:imageFriendAddOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    else {

        UIImage *imageFriendAddOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Off_userAddFriend@2x"];
        [myButton setBackgroundImage:imageFriendAddOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }
```

**Always in cellForRowAtIndexPath I entered the search mode with a Boolean filtering users**

```
PFObject *object = [userArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!isFiltered) {

        cell.user_photoProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];
        cell.user_photoProfile.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.user_photoProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
        cell.user_photoProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.user_photoProfile.file = [object objectForKey:NPUserKey_PHOTOPROFILE];
        [cell.user_photoProfile loadInBackground];


        NSString *nameText = [object objectForKey:NPUserKey_NOMECOGNOME];
        cell.label_UserNomeCognome.text = nameText;
        cell.itemText = nameText;





    }

    else {

        PFObject *filteredObject = [filteredUserArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.user_photoProfile.file = [filteredObject objectForKey:NPUserKey_PHOTOPROFILE];
        cell.user_photoProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];
        [cell.user_photoProfile.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [cell.user_photoProfile  .layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
        cell.user_photoProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [cell.user_photoProfile loadInBackground];

        NSString *str = [filteredObject objectForKey:NPUserKey_NOMECOGNOME];
        cell.label_UserNomeCognome.text = str;
        cell.itemText = str;



    }
```

**This however is the structure of the filter for the UISearchBar**

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *) searchText{

    if (searchText.length ==0){
        isFiltered = NO;
    }

    else {
        isFiltered = YES;
        filteredUserArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];




        for(PFObject *object in self.userArray) {
            NSString *str = [object objectForKey:NPUserKey_NOMECOGNOME];
            NSRange stringRange =[str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (stringRange.location !=NSNotFound) {
                [filteredUserArray addObject:object];


            }
        }
    }

    [tableViewFindUser reloadData];
}
```

**Add also the method for the selected button**

```
-(void)tapped:(UIButton *)sender andEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableViewFindUser];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewFindUser indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

    if ([self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray[indexPath.row]boolValue]) {
        [self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@(0)];



        UIImage *imageFriendAddOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Off_userAddFriend@2x"];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:imageFriendAddOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1);
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInNewView" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
        sender.alpha = 1.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];


        PFUser *userFiltered = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:NPFriendClass];
        [query whereKey:NPFriend_DaUser equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [query whereKey:NPFriendRequestStatus equalTo:@"Richiesta In Attesa"];
        [query whereKey:@"OBJECT_USER_ID" equalTo:userFiltered.objectId];
        [query includeKey:NPFriend_AUser];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

            if(!error) {

                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSLog(@"ELIMINATO: %@", object);
                    [object deleteInBackground];
                }
            }

            else {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];




    } else {

        [self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@(1)];

        UIImage *imageFriendAddOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"On_userAddFriend@2x"];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:imageFriendAddOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1);
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInNewView" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
        sender.alpha = 1.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];





        PFObject *richiesta = [PFObject objectWithClassName:NPFriendClass];

        if (!isFiltered) {

            PFUser *userNotFiltered = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            [richiesta setObject:userNotFiltered forKey:NPFriend_AUser];
            [richiesta setObject:userNotFiltered.objectId forKey:@"OBJECT_USER_ID"];
            [richiesta setObject:userNotFiltered.username forKey:@"Username"];
            [richiesta setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:NPFriend_DaUser];
            [richiesta setObject:@"Richiesta In Attesa" forKey:NPFriendRequestStatus];
            [richiesta setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"RECORD_INSERT"];
            [richiesta saveInBackground];

            NSLog(@"AMICO: %@", richiesta);

        }


        else {

            PFUser *userFiltered = [self.filteredUserArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [richiesta setObject:userFiltered forKey:NPFriend_AUser];
            [richiesta setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:NPFriend_DaUser];
            [richiesta setObject:@"Richiesta In Attesa" forKey:NPFriendRequestStatus];
            [richiesta saveInBackground];

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Dont save the state in the another arry, use the same array either in normal mode or search mode.for the same array add another key for the object and save the state in that.

Comment: Hello ... I tried to use the same array self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray, I created mybutton and myButton1 

= mybutton for unfiltered 
myButton1 = for the filtered 

but seems not to work ... I also tried to give the tag 100 to 101 for non-filtered and the filtrates, even this seems to work ... 

I misunderstood what you wanted to tell me ???

Comment: on button action you need to change the value in the self.buttonPressedSelectedRowArray array. Are you doing this.

Comment: Forgive me but my english is not 'great ..: D could you give me an example of what you speak?

Comment: to better understand I also edited my post with the method for the selected button

Comment: Hi is issue resolved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61727/discussion-between-rory-and-ramesh-muthe).

Comment: no I still have not solved I'm waiting for someone to help me in some way